# Why the width of a div element alters the content of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have this page which changes itself based on the width of the screen. If the screen is large, I have this nav bar with a div with categories:

[image: large_screen]

and if the screen is small, I have this nav bar:

[image: small_screen]

The problem arises when I want to add a width property to the div element "dropdown-menu". If the width property doesn't exist, the page resizes like in the images above. However, if I add width property, I get this view when the screen is small and the div element doesn't disappear:

[image: wrong_view]

This is my code:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 115px;
    margin-left: -105px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 155px; 
}

.right-items, .left-items {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div className = "categories">
  <ul className = "link-style">Categories</ul>
  <img src = {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/down-arrow.png'} alt = "Down arrow"/>
  <div className='dropdown-menu'>
      <ul className='left-items'>
          <li>Funny</li>
          <li>Animals</li>
          <li>Games</li>
      </ul>

      <ul className='right-items'>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>Science</li>
          <li>Planet</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Is there a problem with the width property or why is this issue only when I add it?
All suggestions are welcome.
I couldn't find anything similar online.

Thank you!